# Encountered EOF incorrectly while reading file

Tags: c, eof

Following is my program. I try to read the file `rgb_values.txt` and transfer its data to `out.txt`. `rgb_values.txt` is very long with about 2.7 million lines, but when I run the program and check `out.txt`; it has only 2.5 million lines (2554994 lines to be exact) which means that in this line the program reads to **EOF**. However, this should not be the case. I don't know what went wrong

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int count=0;
void getOneByte(FILE *plaintext,unsigned char *pt,int i){
    char line[4]={0x0};
    fgets(line,sizeof(line),plaintext);
    int x1=0x0;
    char str[4];
    sprintf(str,"%s",line);
    sscanf(str,"%02x ",&x1);
    pt[i]=x1;
}
void get16Bytes(FILE *plaintext,unsigned char * pt){
    int i=0;
    char sh;
    for (int i = 0; i <=15; i++)
    {
        getOneByte(plaintext,pt,i);
        if((sh=fgetc(plaintext))!=EOF){
            ungetc(sh,plaintext);
        }
        else{
            ungetc(sh,plaintext);
            break;
        }
    }
}

void write16Bytes(FILE *ciphertext,unsigned char *ct){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        if(count == 0){
            fprintf(ciphertext,"%02x",ct[i]);
            count++;
        }
        else if(count == 1){
            fprintf(ciphertext," %02x",ct[i]);
            count++;
        }
        else if(count == 2){
            fprintf(ciphertext," %02x\n",ct[i]);
            count = 0;
        }
    }  
}
int main(){
    FILE *fp=fopen("rgb_values.txt","r");
    FILE *fo=fopen("out.txt","w");
    char ch;
    unsigned char pt[16];
    int i=15;
    int cnt=0;
    while(1){
        memset(pt,'a',sizeof(pt));
        get16Bytes(fp,pt);
        if((ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
            ungetc(ch,fp);
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
        write16Bytes(fo,pt);
        cnt++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 1;
}
```

[Link for rgb_values.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q7JB9NagrxWdhwGWikV4PX0RZvdhK6LO/view?usp=share_link)

[Link for my out.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p6obrDt9GiLlu_8BB4Zhm6psUzB1yBGe/view?usp=share_link)

Part of my input file:

```
c1 c1 c1
ff ff ff
ff ff ff
ff ff ff
ff ff ff
fe fe fe
fd fd fd
ff ff ff
fb fb fb
fe fe fe
fe fe fe
ff ff ff
fb fb fb
f1 f1 f1
e9 e9 e9
e6 e6 e6
e5 e5 e5
e5 e5 e5
e5 e5 e5
e5 e5 e5
e5 e5 e5
e5 e5 e5
e5 e5 e5
e5 e5 e5
e5 e5 e5
e5 e5 e5
e5 e5 e5
e2 e2 e2
e5 e5 e5
e7 e7 e7
e5 e5 e5
e4 e4 e4
e3 e3 e3
e3 e3 e3
e8 e8 e8
de de de
9c 9c 9c
3b 3b 3b
01 01 01
02 02 02
00 00 00
02 02 02
0a 0a 0a
```

Comment: Your `getOneByte` function, why not `sscanf` directly from `line`? And why don't use `strtol` instead? And read directly into `pt[i]` instead of the temporary dummy variable `x1`?

Comment: And note that [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an **`int`** value. Which is *very* important when you want to compare to the `int` value `EOF`.

Comment: Oh and please include a small sample from the file you read.

Comment: And why is `count` a *global* variable, when you only use it *locally* inside a single function? At least make it a `static` local variable if you need to keep its value between calls.

Comment: OT: you don't check if `fopen` succeeds.

Comment: `sprintf(str,"%s",line);` Why don't you directly use `line` with `sscanf`?

Comment: Lastly, if there are three value on each line of the input and output file, why not read the whole line and parse the three values at once? Same then with writing. Why bother with 16 values, which is not a multiple of three, that only makes the code weirder. If you use multiple of three then at least you could skip the `count` variable for state. And can simplify quite a lot for all your functions.

Comment: Oh and please don't include headers you don't actually need. Like the `<math.h>` header. With he code you show, all you really need is the `<stdio.h>` header, which you include twice.

Comment: If you reach the end of the file, `fgets` will return `NULL`. You can use that result instead of all that stuff reading an extra character and pushing it back into the file stream that you are doing on different levels of functions.

Comment: variable `count` is a signal for formatting output data. I need the output file only three bytes of data displayed per line.

Comment: Do you need to handle input files that have more or less than 3 values per line? Otherwise you can just use simple functions that read 3 values at once and write 3 values at once per line without all that singly value handling.

Comment: @Gerhardh No, actually this file comes from an image and I transform all of its pixels into rgb values and display like this.But I need to handle 16 bytes per loop in another code to encrypt and display 3 values per line in order to transform back to an image.

Comment: @Gerhardh Alright I will try `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know what went wrong

Coding is not defensive as it does not look for unexpected events.

To learn *what went wrong*, improve code's error detection.

In other words, don't trust user input - its evil.

---

**Why read only 3 bytes?**

The below reads, at most 3 bytes from the file, leaving the remainder of a line for later reading.

```
char line[4]={0x0};
fgets(line,sizeof(line),plaintext);
```

It does **not** read only 3 bytes from a file and toss the remainder of the line.

**Check return value of `fgets()`**

```
// fgets(line,sizeof(line),plaintext);
if (fgets(line,sizeof(line),plaintext) == NULL) {
  TBD_alert();
}
```

**Use `int`**

`int fgetc()` can return 257 different values.  Saving in a `char` loses something.

```
// char ch;
int ch;

// char sh;
int sh;
```

**Lack of error checking**

What if `sscanf(str,"%02x ",&x1)` returns 0 (no conversion)?

**What if 4 is too small?**

Should an extra white-space exist, (space, `'\r'`, ...), 4 is simply too small.

```
char line[4]={0x0};
fgets(line,sizeof(line),plaintext);
```

Instead read a complete *line* with `fgets()` allowing at least a 2x size buffer over expected size and tolerate extra white-space or a missing `'\n'` on the last line.  Given a line of `"c1 c1 c1\n"`, use a buffer size of (3*3 + 1)*2.

I suspect many `'\r'` lurking about.

**Avoid UB.  Use matching specifiers**

`"%x"` matches an `unsigned`, not `int`.

```
// int x1=0x0;
unsigned x1 = 0x0;  
...
 // '0' is useless, '2' is not needed.  Trailing space is useless
// sscanf(str,"%02x ",&x1);  
sscanf(str,"%x", &x1);    // Check return value - not shown
```

or saved directly

```
sscanf(str, "%hhx", &pt[i]);
```

**What is other than 3 values per line?**

Sample code to read a line of 3 hex values and detect lots of errors.

```
#define EXPECTED_LINE_SIZE (3*3 + 1 /* for the \0 */)

char line[EXPECTED_LINE_SIZE * 2];
if (fgets(line, sizeof line, plaintext) == NULL) {
  return failure;
}
int n = 0;
unsigned val[3];
sscanf(line "%2x %2x %2x %n", &val[0], &val[1], &val[2], &n);
if (n == 0 || line[n] != '\0') {
  return failure;
}
```

**Check if `fopen()` failed**

```
FILE *fp=fopen("rgb_values.txt","r");
FILE *fo=fopen("out.txt","w");

if (fp == NULL || fo == NULL) {
  TBD_Error_out();  // Add your code here
}
```

Comment: Is `TBD_alert` equal to `return failure`?

Comment: @ShepardMerose A made-up name to indicate you need to code some To-Be-Determined code that alerts the user to an unexpected problem - or some other code as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to copy from one file to the other, open in binary mode, and in a loop `fread` a buffer of say 4KiB, and then `fwrite` it to the other file. Quick and easy:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *in  = fopen(..., "rb");
    FILE *out = fopen(..., "wb");

    if (!in || !out)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    char buffer[4096];
    size_t nread;
    while ((nread = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, in)) > 0)
        fwrite(buffer, 1, nread, out);
}
```

Otherwise if you need to read it as strings use `fgets` and `fputs` in a loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *in  = fopen(..., "r");
    FILE *out = fopen(..., "w");

    if (!in || !out)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, in) != NULL)
        fputs(line, out);
}
```

Or as I mentioned, `fgets` to read a whole line, `sscanf` to parse out all three values, pass back to the calling function (together with a file read success status), and `fprintf` all three values at once:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int read_values(FILE *in, int *values)
{
    char line[256];
    if (fgets(line, sizeof line, in) == NULL)
        return 0;  // Failure to read

    if (sscanf(line("%x %x %x", &values[0], &values[1], &values[2]) != 3)
        return 0;  // Failure to parse

    return 1;  // Success
}

void write_values(FILE *out, int *values)
{
    fprintf(out, "%02x %02x %02x\n", values[0], values[1], values[2]);
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *in  = fopen(..., "r");
    FILE *out = fopen(..., "w");

    if (!in || !out)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    int values[3];
    while (read_values(in, values))
        write_values(out, values);
}
```

Note that I don't close the files. If your program is doing more after this, then they should really be closed. If the program just exits, then the system will close them for us.